# Create menu entry and desktop icon for application installed from .tar.gz

Tags: fedora, desktop, menu, menu-editor

For install an application from `.tar.gz` I follow this steps (I will take phpStorm as the example):

- Download the `.tar.gz` file and uncompress under `~/apps`. After run this with the given example I end with this path: `~/apps/phpStorm`
- Create a symlink for the executable in `~/bin` (so all the executables of each app ends there)
- Add `~/bin` to the `$PATH` using the `~/.bashrc` file

Having that I am able to execute them from the console. Now I want to go beyond and add an icon on the menu and the desktop <strike>but I can't find a good docs for achieve this.</strike>

I have created a file under `/home/reynierpm/.local/share/applications/.desktop-file` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=phpStorm
Comment=PhpStorm is a PHP IDE that actually ‘gets’ your code. It supports PHP 5.3/5.4/5.5/5.6/7.0.
GenericName=PHP Editor
Exec=phpstorm
Icon=/home/reynierpm/apps/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
```

I found somewhere that this should be enough and a icon would appear on the menu but isn't showing up.

I know there is a GUI tool name Alacarte but I would like to go trough the hard way: console.

Can any help me to build the entry for the menu and the icon for the desktop for this app and possibly use the example as a template?

I am using Fedora 24.

Comment: When placing launchers in `~/.local/share/applications` you have to mark them as trusted - i.e. either double click it > follow instructions or `chmod +x` and add `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` on top.