# How to iconify Anaconda Navigator on the task bar?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, icons

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bionic Beaver. I have installed Anaconda and to open it, I have to type `anaconda-navigator` in the terminal to open it every time.

Is there a way to iconify it on my taskbar so that I can open it in one click?

I am facing the same problem with gedit too. To open it, I have to type `gedit` in the terminal.

Anaconda and gedit are not present in the menu and I have to type commands in the terminal to open them. Can I iconify them on the taskbar?

Comment: Create a `~/.local/share/applications/anaconda.desktop` file like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322743/create-menu-entry-and-desktop-icon-for-application-installed-from-tar-gz .

Comment: @IporSircer ... could you please explain the process?

Comment: There are well detailed howtos. https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

Answer (score 4):

This works in Ubuntu 18.10:

1. Download and install alacarte. sudo apt install alacarte
2. Find and save an icon for Anaconda Navigator.
3. Find where Anaconda Navigator is stored.  "which anaconda-navigator" should disclose the location.  Mine is in /home/jim/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator
4. In alacarte select "New Item" and fill out the info.  Change the icon there to the one you saved.  It is difficult later because you must go back to alacarte. You can change the icon by clicking on the default icon and selecting the one you saved to your computer.
5. Save the shortcut. Then you can close alacarte.
6. Go to "Show Applications" which is the grid at the bottom of your favorites.  You should see your newly created shortcut and the icon you assigned to it. Right click that icon and select Add to Favorites.
7. If you want to modify the link or icon you must go back to "alacarte".