# How to create a desktop icon for an application on RHEL 8?

Tags: rhel, gnome, desktop, .desktop, launcher

I copied an existing and working `.desktop` file for an application that can be launched from *Applications* → *Favorites* into `~/Desktop` but the file is displayed on and opened from the desktop as text file only.

[Chapter 1. Getting started with GNOME](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/getting-started-with-gnome_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8#creating-a-desktop-icon-for-a-file_managing-desktop-icons) just mentions:

> #### 1.4.3. Creating a desktop icon for a file
>
> This procedure creates a desktop icon for an existing file.

and nothing about an application/launcher.

There's a comment to *[Create menu entry and desktop icon for application installed from .tar.gz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322743/88374)* for Fedora 24:

> When placing launchers in `~/.local/share/applications` you have to mark them as trusted - i.e. either double click it > follow instructions or `chmod +x` and add `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` on top.

Does this apply to RHEL 8 as well? Where, as mentioned above, when double-clicking my `.desktop` it opens in a text editor.

A solution for both *Gnome Classic* and *Gnome Shell* would be highly appreciated (if it's not the same anyway).

Comment: .desktop files need special permission, see my question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-18-04-tls-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Right-click* on the desktop icon → *Allow Launching* works without prior `chmod +x` on the `.desktop` file in *Gnome Shell* and *Gnome Classic* alike.